# Unexpected shape for deconv layer

Tags: caffe, deconvolution

I work on a deconv layer which upscales 64 channels : 64x48x48 => 64x96x96.

```py
layer {
    bottom: "layer41_conv"
    top: "layertest_upsample"
    name: "layertest_upsample"
    type: "Deconvolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        group: 64
        kernel_size: 2
        pad: 0
        stride: 2
    }
}
```

When I print the shape of the parameters :
(64,1,2,2).
I was expected something like :
(64,64,2,2) because of 64 channels in input and 64 channels in output. 
Can anyone explain me what's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `group: 64`

What `group` does is (according to [manual](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/convolution.html)):

> `group` (`g`) [default 1]: If `g > 1`, we restrict the connectivity of each filter to a subset of the input. Specifically, the input and output channels are separated into `g` groups, and the `k`-th output group channels will be only connected to the `k`-th input group channels.

In your case you grouped all 64 channels into 64 groups - this that the `k`-th input channel is mapped (in isolation) by a 2x2 kernel to the `k`-th output channel. Over all you have 64 such 2x2 mappings and this is why your weight blob is 64x1x2x2 and not 64x64x2x2.
If you remove the `group: 64` you'll have the full weight matrix you expect.